# adding column names to csv file through php

Tags: php, csv

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to add data to CSV file whenever a person registers. I want to ask, is there a way to add column names?

This is my php code:

```
$handle = fopen("data.csv", 'a');

fwrite($handle, $doi. ", " .$per_add. ", " .$pre_add."\n"); 

fclose($handle);

header("Location: thankyou.html");
exit;
```

Comment: Column names are only added once so this wouldn't be an appropriate place to add them, unless I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The column names are just the first line of the csv. so you just check if the file exist (and is non-empty). If it does not exist, create it with the column names as the first line.

Comment: Too bad this got downvoted. I was trying to learn the guy to fish instead of giving him the fish on a platter.

Comment: Don't worry, I upvoted it as it works!

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in my comment. Adding a header implies this is added to the top of a CSV file. This needs to only be done once (i.e. check if a file exists and if not write the header first). However if you already have files which you want to prepend a header to you can do one of the following:

If your files are small you can do this:

```
function prependHeader($headerDataArray) {
    $currentData = file_get_contents("data.csv");               
    $handle = fopen("data.csv", 'w'); //Truncate it
    fputcsv($handle, $headerDataArray);
    fwrite($handle, $currentData); 
    fclose($handle);    
}
```

If your files are too large to store in memory then you'll need to basically rewrite the whole file line by line and then remove the old file:

```
function prependHeader($headerDataArray) {
    $readHandle = fopen("data.csv");               
    $writeHandle = fopen("newData.csv", 'w'); //Truncate it
    fputcsv($writeHandle, $headerDataArray);
    while (($line = fgetcsv($readHandle))) {
         fputcsv($writeHandle,$line);
    }
    fclose($readHandle);    
    fclose($writeHandle);    
    unlink("data.csv");
    rename("newData.csv", "data.csv");
}
```